# how to use drawArc()

Tags: java, drawing

i want to draw this arc in a panel that the preferedSize is set to (200,50):

[image]

i found it hard to understand what does the parameters in `drawArc()`. how to draw this one?

Comment: Did you search the forum/web for examples that use the `drawArc(...)` method? Then you test the examples and customize the parameters. Learn by example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the arguements read the javadoc: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: i need the example code. the arc, for example is drawn in a panel that have preferedSize to 200,50

Comment: `i need the example code.` - Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. Show use that you have made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int length, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
```

Used to draw an arc inside an imaginary rectangle whose upper left corner is at (x,y).  The arc is drawn from the startAngle to startAngle + arcAngle and is measured in degrees.  A startAngle of 0º points horizontally to the right (like the unit circle in math).  Positive is a counterclockwise rotation starting at 0º